# How to convert the value of success data from ajax to PHP Laravel blade?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

This is my ajax function calling the route to controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: '/getRooms/{{ $roomtype->name }}',
           data: "",
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
       })
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller method called from the ajax function and route.

```
public function numberOfRooms($room_name, Request $request)
{
    $room_model = new room;
    $no_rooms = $room_model->where('rmtype', '=', $room_name)->get()->count();
    return $no_rooms;
}
```

This is the value returned from ajax success and I need it to be converted to a PHP value to display it in laravel blade for my foreach statement

[image]

Comment: You cannot display PHP from Javascript because PHP executes first, by the time you JavaScript. PHP has already finished. What you need now is HTML manipulation via Javascript. You can do that with vanilla javascript, jquery, vuejs, angularjs, reactjs, anyOtherJS. But not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert to PHP since PHP executes first and synchronous process. But Javascript was asynchronous process. You can do a something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "get",
                      url: '/getRooms/{{ $roomtype->name }}',
                      data: "",
                      success: function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                          $('#display_value').text(data.your_pass_value);    
                      }
                  })
                });
    </script>
```

---

In your HTML:

```
<span id="display_value"></span>
```

Hopes answered your question.